# can`t edit anything in exchange admin center 2019

Tags: exchange, exchange-2019

recently in a new exchange 2019 installation server I'm facing a problem, every time i edit anything in ECP it turns into some kind of code and make me unable to save or edit it agian!
this is the picture of how it turns after just editing it
[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Do you have all the CU installed ?

Comment: yes it`s 15.2.1118.7, and it`s newly installed

Comment: What version of Exchange 2019 CU are you using? Do you also have another version of Exchange server to use? There is an error in Exchange 2019. Whenever try to click on Exchange 2019 Database through Exchange 2019 ECP it generates error if you co-existence with other Exchange server.

Comment: it is 15.2.1118.7 and its just the only exchange server here. I've tried to update this to latest version but didn't find the source! I've got problems with this server and need to edit things but I can't!! I do'nt know if installing again on the server would help! or try to repair the installation

Comment: You can find the new version of Exchange 2019 CU in this Microsoft Document :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/new-features/build-numbers-and-release-dates?view=exchserver-2019
Now the newest version of  Exchange 2019 is 15.2.1118.25.
You can update the newest CU version of  Exchange  2019 then to check whether the problem still exists.

Comment: Have your problems been solved? If you still have some issues ,you can reply ,we will try our best to help you.